# how to hide a <h4> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I tried to give a id to a `<h4>` tag so later I am able to show or hide it but it didn't work. When i try to use the getElementByID and alert the value I get a alert box saying "undefined".

So I would like to know if there is other way to hide/show an  tag?

My code is located [here](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/9105/semttulost.png).

What I want to do is hide/show the h4 depending on the value of the Category combobox

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But you'll need to show your actual html and javascript that you're trying to do this with. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: can you show us how did you assign the id to your tag?

Comment: this question shows a huge lack of effort both in researching and phrasing without actual code

Comment: @micha How you know it'll be the first `h4` in the document to hide?

Comment: im writing code for a spiceworks plugin it is java script but not like the normal js

Comment: Never mind what it is, post it here, we'll see...

Comment: thanks to the down votes now i cant post img just give me a sec

Comment: @user181891 there it is: `comment_Software:` is the id.

Comment: buit if i try to alert the value of that id i dont get "Software"

Comment: @user181891 Look at your earlier question, in one of the answers there were correct characters which can be used in `id`, colon is not one of them.

Comment: @user181891 Exactly. It seems you have colons in other `id`'s also, you've to remove all of them to get the page work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the best I can do without knowing your code:

**HTML**:

```
<h4 id="myH4">Hello World</h4>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("myH4").style.display="none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myH4").style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted?

Comment: but how do i know what < h4 > im hiding?

Comment: If you'll look at the <h4> tag, you'll notice it has an attribute called 'id'. The ID attribute is specific to a particular tag, providing you set it, and you can find the <h4> element by looking up its ID, which is what `document.getElementById` does.

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted a second time?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I guess it's because you gave everything to OP without letting hiw to show what he tried. I did not downvote your answer...

Comment: @LucM: Well, I was just trying answer his question... :)

Comment: It would seem that a very ticked off somebody is systematically going through my answers and questions and downvoting them. The trail starts here. *sigh*